# What are the proper changes for spring-cloud-config on Spring Boot 2.4.x?

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot

I have been digging through the documentation for hours and can still not make sense of what actually needs to change in the web app I'm working on.
In the original, pre 2.4.x version `application.yml` and `application-local.yml` do not have any cloud config related properties

All of the cloud config stuff is in `bootstrap.yml` divided into documents for generic and then environments:

```yaml
spring:
  application:
    name: my_app
  cloud:
    config:
      label: develop
      uri: https://my.local.server
      username: user
      password: password
      enabled: true
---
spring:
  profiles: int
  cloud:
    config:
      label: develop
      uri: https://my.int.server
      username: user
      password: password
      enabled: true
---
…
```

Switching `spring.profiles: int` to `spring.config.activate.on-profile: int` in `bootstrap.yml` was simple enough to figure out. What I can't manage to find is what else I need to add (and where) to allow the config to be read from the server properly. I tried adding variations of `spring.config.import: "optional:configserver:"` to `application.yml` and while they have solved the error about that property being missing, none of them have allowed the values to be found. (I tried `"configserver:"`, `"configserver:https://my.local.server"`, & `"optional:configserver:https://my.local.server"`)

I'm sure I'm missing something totally obvious, but I have no idea what it could be.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to get rid of `bootstrap.yml` and put every property in `application.yml`. Something along the following lines:

```yaml
(...)

spring:
  application:
    name: my_app
  cloud:
    config:
      label: develop
      uri: https://my.local.server
      username: user
      password: password
      enabled: true
---
spring:
  config:
    activate:
      on-profile: int
  cloud:
    config:
      label: develop
      uri: https://my.int.server
      username: user
      password: password
      enabled: true
---

(...)
```

Additionally, for Spring Boot. 2.4.6, make sure you have the following dependencies:

```xml
<dependencyManagement>
    <dependencies>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>io.pivotal.spring.cloud</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-cloud-services-dependencies</artifactId>
            <version>3.2.1.RELEASE</version>
            <type>pom</type>
            <scope>import</scope>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.cloud</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-cloud-dependencies</artifactId>
            <version>2020.0.3</version>
            <type>pom</type>
            <scope>import</scope>
        </dependency>
    </dependencies>
</dependencyManagement>
```

Comment: Do I also need to get rid of all the `application-<env>.yml` files?

Comment: Yes, everything should be included in `application.yml`

Comment: Thank you João for your answer. Is there any proper announcement/ documentation from spring people about these changes?

Comment: Yes, there is. On their Github you will find the release notes of each minor version (example: https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-boot/wiki/Spring-Boot-2.6-Release-Notes). I would recommend their reading every time a new minor version is available.